# http://datatables.net/tn/3 : Cannot reinitialize datatable

Tags: jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I want to perform row grouping for my ajax sourced data in my datatables.
This is my code for html:-

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0-beta.2/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="NewFile.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>


    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0-beta.2/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "ajax": 'arrays.txt'
        } );
    } );
  </script>
  <script>

  </script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "columnDefs": [
                { "visible": false, "targets": 2 }
            ],
            "order": [[ 2, 'asc' ]],
            "displayLength": 25,
            "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
                var api = this.api();
                var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
                var last=null;

                api.column(2, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
                    if ( last !== group ) {
                        $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                            '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                        );

                        last = group;
                    }
                } );
            }
        } );

        // Order by the grouping
        $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr.group', function () {
            var currentOrder = table.order()[0];
            if ( currentOrder[0] === 2 && currentOrder[1] === 'asc' ) {
                table.order( [ 2, 'desc' ] ).draw();
            }
            else {
                table.order( [ 2, 'asc' ] ).draw();
            }
        } );
    } );

  </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And this is my ajax arrays.txt file:-

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",
      "5421",
      "2011/04/25",
      "$320,800"
    ],
    [
      "Garrett Winters",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "8422",
      "2011/07/25",
      "$170,750"
    ],
    [
      "Ashton Cox",
      "Junior Technical Author",
      "San Francisco",
      "1562",
      "2009/01/12",
      "$86,000"
    ],
    [
      "Cedric Kelly",
      "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "Edinburgh",
      "6224",
      "2012/03/29",
      "$433,060"
    ],
    [
      "Airi Satou",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "5407",
      "2008/11/28",
      "$162,700"
    ],
    [
      "Brielle Williamson",
      "Integration Specialist",
      "New York",
      "4804",
      "2012/12/02",
      "$372,000"
    ],
    [
      "Herrod Chandler",
      "Sales Assistant",
      "San Francisco",
      "9608",
      "2012/08/06",
      "$137,500"
    ],
    [
      "Rhona Davidson",
      "Integration Specialist",
      "Tokyo",
      "6200",
      "2010/10/14",
      "$327,900"
    ],
    [
      "Colleen Hurst",
      "Javascript Developer",
      "San Francisco",
      "2360",
      "2009/09/15",
      "$205,500"
    ],
    [
      "Sonya Frost",
      "Software Engineer",
      "Edinburgh",
      "1667",
      "2008/12/13",
      "$103,600"
    ],
    [
      "Jena Gaines",
      "Office Manager",
      "London",
      "3814",
      "2008/12/19",
      "$90,560"
    ],
    [
      "Quinn Flynn",
      "Support Lead",
      "Edinburgh",
      "9497",
      "2013/03/03",
      "$342,000"
    ],
    [
      "Charde Marshall",
      "Regional Director",
      "San Francisco",
      "6741",
      "2008/10/16",
      "$470,600"
    ],
    [
      "Haley Kennedy",
      "Senior Marketing Designer",
      "London",
      "3597",
      "2012/12/18",
      "$313,500"
    ],
    [
      "Tatyana Fitzpatrick",
      "Regional Director",
      "London",
      "1965",
      "2010/03/17",
      "$385,750"
    ],
    [
      "Michael Silva",
      "Marketing Designer",
      "London",
      "1581",
      "2012/11/27",
      "$198,500"
    ],
    [
      "Paul Byrd",
      "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)",
      "New York",
      "3059",
      "2010/06/09",
      "$725,000"
    ],
    [
      "Gloria Little",
      "Systems Administrator",
      "New York",
      "1721",
      "2009/04/10",
      "$237,500"
    ],
    [
      "Bradley Greer",
      "Software Engineer",
      "London",
      "2558",
      "2012/10/13",
      "$132,000"
    ],
    [
      "Dai Rios",
      "Personnel Lead",
      "Edinburgh",
      "2290",
      "2012/09/26",
      "$217,500"
    ],
    [
      "Jenette Caldwell",
      "Development Lead",
      "New York",
      "1937",
      "2011/09/03",
      "$345,000"
    ],
    [
      "Yuri Berry",
      "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)",
      "New York",
      "6154",
      "2009/06/25",
      "$675,000"
    ],
    [
      "Caesar Vance",
      "Pre-Sales Support",
      "New York",
      "8330",
      "2011/12/12",
      "$106,450"
    ],
    [
      "Doris Wilder",
      "Sales Assistant",
      "Sidney",
      "3023",
      "2010/09/20",
      "$85,600"
    ],
    [
      "Angelica Ramos",
      "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)",
      "London",
      "5797",
      "2009/10/09",
      "$1,200,000"
    ],
    [
      "Gavin Joyce",
      "Developer",
      "Edinburgh",
      "8822",
      "2010/12/22",
      "$92,575"
    ],
    [
      "Jennifer Chang",
      "Regional Director",
      "Singapore",
      "9239",
      "2010/11/14",
      "$357,650"
    ],
    [
      "Brenden Wagner",
      "Software Engineer",
      "San Francisco",
      "1314",
      "2011/06/07",
      "$206,850"
    ],
    [
      "Fiona Green",
      "Chief Operating Officer (COO)",
      "San Francisco",
      "2947",
      "2010/03/11",
      "$850,000"
    ],
    [
      "Shou Itou",
      "Regional Marketing",
      "Tokyo",
      "8899",
      "2011/08/14",
      "$163,000"
    ],
    [
      "Michelle House",
      "Integration Specialist",
      "Sidney",
      "2769",
      "2011/06/02",
      "$95,400"
    ],
    [
      "Suki Burks",
      "Developer",
      "London",
      "6832",
      "2009/10/22",
      "$114,500"
    ],
    [
      "Prescott Bartlett",
      "Technical Author",
      "London",
      "3606",
      "2011/05/07",
      "$145,000"
    ],
    [
      "Gavin Cortez",
      "Team Leader",
      "San Francisco",
      "2860",
      "2008/10/26",
      "$235,500"
    ],
    [
      "Martena Mccray",
      "Post-Sales support",
      "Edinburgh",
      "8240",
      "2011/03/09",
      "$324,050"
    ],
    [
      "Unity Butler",
      "Marketing Designer",
      "San Francisco",
      "5384",
      "2009/12/09",
      "$85,675"
    ],
    [
      "Howard Hatfield",
      "Office Manager",
      "San Francisco",
      "7031",
      "2008/12/16",
      "$164,500"
    ],
    [
      "Hope Fuentes",
      "Secretary",
      "San Francisco",
      "6318",
      "2010/02/12",
      "$109,850"
    ],
    [
      "Vivian Harrell",
      "Financial Controller",
      "San Francisco",
      "9422",
      "2009/02/14",
      "$452,500"
    ],
    [
      "Timothy Mooney",
      "Office Manager",
      "London",
      "7580",
      "2008/12/11",
      "$136,200"
    ],
    [
      "Jackson Bradshaw",
      "Director",
      "New York",
      "1042",
      "2008/09/26",
      "$645,750"
    ],
    [
      "Olivia Liang",
      "Support Engineer",
      "Singapore",
      "2120",
      "2011/02/03",
      "$234,500"
    ],
    [
      "Bruno Nash",
      "Software Engineer",
      "London",
      "6222",
      "2011/05/03",
      "$163,500"
    ],
    [
      "Sakura Yamamoto",
      "Support Engineer",
      "Tokyo",
      "9383",
      "2009/08/19",
      "$139,575"
    ],
    [
      "Thor Walton",
      "Developer",
      "New York",
      "8327",
      "2013/08/11",
      "$98,540"
    ],
    [
      "Finn Camacho",
      "Support Engineer",
      "San Francisco",
      "2927",
      "2009/07/07",
      "$87,500"
    ],
    [
      "Serge Baldwin",
      "Data Coordinator",
      "Singapore",
      "8352",
      "2012/04/09",
      "$138,575"
    ],
    [
      "Zenaida Frank",
      "Software Engineer",
      "New York",
      "7439",
      "2010/01/04",
      "$125,250"
    ],
    [
      "Zorita Serrano",
      "Software Engineer",
      "San Francisco",
      "4389",
      "2012/06/01",
      "$115,000"
    ],
    [
      "Jennifer Acosta",
      "Junior Javascript Developer",
      "Edinburgh",
      "3431",
      "2013/02/01",
      "$75,650"
    ],
    [
      "Cara Stevens",
      "Sales Assistant",
      "New York",
      "3990",
      "2011/12/06",
      "$145,600"
    ],
    [
      "Hermione Butler",
      "Regional Director",
      "London",
      "1016",
      "2011/03/21",
      "$356,250"
    ],
    [
      "Lael Greer",
      "Systems Administrator",
      "London",
      "6733",
      "2009/02/27",
      "$103,500"
    ],
    [
      "Jonas Alexander",
      "Developer",
      "San Francisco",
      "8196",
      "2010/07/14",
      "$86,500"
    ],
    [
      "Shad Decker",
      "Regional Director",
      "Edinburgh",
      "6373",
      "2008/11/13",
      "$183,000"
    ],
    [
      "Michael Bruce",
      "Javascript Developer",
      "Singapore",
      "5384",
      "2011/06/27",
      "$183,000"
    ],
    [
      "Donna Snider",
      "Customer Support",
      "New York",
      "4226",
      "2011/01/25",
      "$112,000"
    ]
  ]
}
```

When i try to run , I get the error message **DataTables warning:table id=example-cannot reinitialize datatable. For more information about this error, see http://datatables.net/tn/3**
So where is the error ?

*********************************************UPDATE******************************************

Now, if i club the 2 javascript code, I **don't get the error, the datatable gets populated but the row grouping doesn't happen**. So where is my error now ? PLEASE HELP !!!! My code:-

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0-beta.2/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="NewFile.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SECTION</th>
                <th>REPORT NAME</th>
                <th>CONTACT PERSON</th>
                <th>LINK TO DOWNLOAD</th>
                <th>METRICS</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>


    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0-beta.2/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <!-- <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "ajax": 'arrays.txt'
        } );
    <!-- } );
    </script>
  <script>

  </script> -->
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {   
      $('#example').dataTable( {
            "ajax": 'arrays.txt'
        } );
      table.destroy();
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            "columnDefs": [
                { "visible": false, "targets": 2 }
            ],
            "order": [[ 2, 'asc' ]],
            "displayLength": 25,
            "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
                var api = this.api();
                var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
                var last=null;

                api.column(2, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
                    if ( last !== group ) {
                        $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                            '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                        );

                        last = group;
                    }
                } );
            }
        } );

        // Order by the grouping
        $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr.group', function () {
            var currentOrder = table.order()[0];
            if ( currentOrder[0] === 2 && currentOrder[1] === 'asc' ) {
                table.order( [ 2, 'desc' ] ).draw();
            }
            else {
                table.order( [ 2, 'asc' ] ).draw();
            }
        } );
    } );

  </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the `tn/3` message is because you were trying to intialize the same table twice. Try doing the dataload in the same function as the rest. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": "arrays.txt",
        "columnDefs": [
            { "visible": false, "targets": 2 }
        ],
        "order": [[ 2, 'asc' ]],
        "displayLength": 25,
        "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
            var api = this.api();
            var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
            var last=null;

            api.column(2, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
                if ( last !== group ) {
                    $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                        '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                    );

                    last = group;
                }
            } );
        }
    } );

    // Order by the grouping
    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr.group', function () {
        var currentOrder = table.order()[0];
        if ( currentOrder[0] === 2 && currentOrder[1] === 'asc' ) {
            table.order( [ 2, 'desc' ] ).draw();
        }
        else {
            table.order( [ 2, 'asc' ] ).draw();
        }
    } );
} );
```